# Late binding Dynamically Resolve Models after entering controller

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core, model-binding

I'm looking for a way to resolve a model after entering into an action in a controller , the simplest way to describe the problem would be:

```
public DTO[] Get(string filterName)
{
    //How can I do this
    this.Resolve<MyCustomType>("MyParamName");
}
```

If you're looking for more information on why I'm trying to do that you can continue reading to get the full picture

**TL;DR**

I'm looking for a way to resolve a model a request, given a parameter name that will always be resolved from query string How can I dynamically register filters from the startup.   I have a class which is going to handle registering my filters.

In my startup class I want to be able to dynamically register filters with my restServices. I have an options that I'm using to pass to my custom ControllerFeatureProvider which roughly looks like so:

```
public class DynamicControllerOptions<TEntity, TDTO>
{
    Dictionary<string, Func<HttpContext, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>> _funcNameToEndpointResolverMap
        = new Dictionary<string, Func<HttpContext, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>>();
    Dictionary<string, List<ParameterOptions>> _filterParamsMap = new Dictionary<string, List<ParameterOptions>>();

    public void AddFilter(string filterName, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
    {
        this._funcNameToEndpointResolverMap.Add(filterName, (httpContext) =>  filter);
    }
    public void AddFilter<T1>(string filterName, Func<T1, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>> filterResolver,
        string param1Name = "param1")
    {
        var parameters = new List<ParameterOptions> { new ParameterOptions { Name = param1Name, Type = typeof(T1) } };
        this._filterParamsMap.Add(filterName, parameters);
        this._funcNameToEndpointResolverMap.Add(filterName, (httpContext) => {
            T1 parameter = this.ResolveParameterFromContext<T1>(httpContext, param1Name);
            var filter = filterResolver(parameter);
            return filter;
        });
    }
}
```

My Controller will keep track of the options and use them to provide filters for paging endpoints and OData.

```
public class DynamicControllerBase<TEntity, TDTO> : ControllerBase
{
    protected DynamicControllerOptions<TEntity, TDTO> _options;
    //...

    public TDTO[] GetList(string filterName = "")
    {
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = 
            this.Options.ResolveFilter(filterName, this.HttpContext);
        var entities = this._context.DbSet<TEntity>().Where(filter).ToList();
        return entities.ToDTO<TDTO>();
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to dynamically resolve a model given the HttpContext, I would think to do something like this to obtain the model but this is pseudo-code that doesn't work

```
private Task<T> ResolveParameterFromContext<T>(HttpContext httpContext, string parameterName)
{
    //var modelBindingContext = httpContext.ToModelBindingContext();
    //var modelBinder = httpContext.Features.OfType<IModelBinder>().Single();
    //return modelBinder.BindModelAsync<T>(parameterName);
}
```

After Digging into the Source, I saw some promising things [ModelBinderFactory](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/ModelBinderFactory.cs) and the [ControllerActionInvoker](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ControllerActionInvoker.cs) These classes are used in the pipeline for model binding,

I would expect the to expose a simple interface to resolve a parameter name from the QueryString, something like this:

```
ModelBindingContext context = new ModelBindingContext();
return context.GetValueFor<T>("MyParamName");
```

However, the only way I see to resolve a model from the model binder is to create fake controller descriptors and mock a ton of things.

How can I accept late bound parameters into my contoller?

Comment: I do not see a use for this.  Furthermore even if you can bind the model based on a string parameter.... you would not be able to use generic method like GetValueFor<T> because T must be resolved a compile time.... this means that the caller must know the type of T at compile time which would defeat the purpose of dynamically binding the type.  This means that the inheritor of DynamicControllerBase must know the type of TDTO.... One thing you can try is receive JSON in the parameter and have each implementation of DynamicControllerBase deserialize the string to a model and viceversa.

Comment: @Darkonekt if you look at the 'AddFilter' method,  you have the typed generic parameters which get stored in a closure when you register the funcs.  It's a bit confusing but I assure you its viable and can work

Comment: I don't want to plug into json, because I dont want to have to change the way to webapi naturally resolve parameters

Comment: If you would explain a bit more about the use case and the real life scenario where this kind of functionality is necessary, that would help a lot. Probably there is even a simpler solution available.. who knows. As for my self, I sometimes like to complicate things.. Just saying..

Comment: @Mr.Blond I have a generic rest service which provides crud and get list functionality.  Sometimes my services need to filter data from get list, but I dont want to have to write an entire service of all I need to to provide a filter

Comment: Is this a use case for GraphQL? By providing the end user with all properties, they can `Frankenstien` any output as needed. Hence they become the filter.

Comment: I would also prefer to use json as @Darkonekt mentioned. I think to change the way how the web api resolves parameters would not require a huge effort.. It might be even less effort than to find a solution for your current implementation.

Comment: @Mr.Blond I'm writing a rest framework, I cant break modelbinding for all the end users

Comment: @johnny5 the problem with your solutions is that you cannot have a dynamic generic parameter..... So eventually one of the callers up the chain have to know the type of T at compile time.... Which defeats the purpose of trying to dynamically resolve T...

Comment: @johnny5 There is no "covariance" in C#. So you cannot define T at runtime... You will eventually have to switch or do a bunch of IF to decide which type to return and box the result inside "object"... but you will innevitably end up having to hardcode the type for T.... So your strategy cannot work dynamically because at some point in the code you will have to have all the possible values for T.   Generic parameters are COMPILE time constants.... You cannot define them at runtime...

Comment: @johnny5 Perhaps some OpCodes to emit IL.... But I am not even sure how that would be dynamic due to the fact that most likely you will need to know the list of possible values of T so that it can emit the right IL....

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing, The purpose to to create short hand controllers for the user so they don't have to define the full architectures, I'll know the types during startup

Answer (score 2):

I agree with your thought

> services need to filter data from get list, but I dont want to have to write an entire service of all I need to to provide a filter

Why write a widget/filter/endpoint  for every possible combination?

Simply provide basic operations to get all data/properties. Then use GraphQL to allow the end user to filter (*model*) it to **their** needs.

From [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/)

`GraphQL is a query language for APIs and a runtime for fulfilling those queries with your existing data. GraphQL provides a complete and understandable description of the data in your API, gives clients the power to ask for exactly what they need and nothing more, makes it easier to evolve APIs over time, and enables powerful developer tools`.

Comment: I've been considering using GraphQL but I'm too tied into my current implementation

Answer (score 2):

We've done this, our code references this site:
[https://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/6/gotchas_in_explicit_model_binding](https://web.archive.org/web/20191018160302/https://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/6/gotchas_in_explicit_model_binding)

Specifically, looking at our code, what does the trick is accepting a FormCollection in your controller method and then using the model binder, model, and form data:

Example taken from link:

```
public ActionResult Save(FormCollection form)
{
var empType = Type.GetType("Example.Models.Employee");
var emp = Activator.CreateInstance(empType);

var binder = Binders.GetBinder(empType);

  var bindingContext = new ModelBindingContext()
  {
    ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => emp, empType),
    ModelState = ModelState,
    ValueProvider = form
  };      

  binder.BindModel(ControllerContext, bindingContext);

  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
   _empRepo.Save(emp);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }

return View();
}
```

(Note: the site appears to be down, link is to to archive.org)

Comment: Thanks for your help, 
Currently, I am not using MVC, e.g (There can be more than 1 input parameter) 
I need to resolve the parameters by the name.  Additionally I'm using .Net-Core I think this is written for the older version .net.  Please complete the method stub: for the answer to be accepted: `this.Resolve<MyCustomType>("MyParamName");`

Comment: Since I don't have an environment to reproduce this minimally, I won't be able to do that - I apologize for missing the dotnetcore requirement.

Comment: I can translate it to .Net-Core that's fine, If you show me how to resolve by parameter name I'll accept

Comment: This is the closest thing to the answer I wanted so I'll give you the bounty

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing dynamic controllers. To solve the problem as a work around.

```
private static TypeBuilder GetTypeBuilder(string assemblyName)
{
    var assemName = new AssemblyName(assemblyName);
    var assemBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    // Create a dynamic module in Dynamic Assembly.
    var moduleBuilder = assemBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("DynamicModule");
    var tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(assemblyName,
            TypeAttributes.Public |
            TypeAttributes.Class |
            TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
            TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
            TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
            TypeAttributes.AutoLayout,
            null);

    return tb;
}
```

I'm hard coding the func in the method for now but I'm sure you can figure out how to pass it down if you need.

```
public static Type CompileResultType(string typeSignature)
{
    TypeBuilder tb = GetTypeBuilder(typeSignature);

    tb.SetParent(typeof(DynamicControllerBase));

    ConstructorBuilder ctor = tb.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);

    // For this controller, I only want a Get method to server Get request
    MethodBuilder myGetMethod =
        tb.DefineMethod("Get",
            MethodAttributes.Public,
            typeof(String), new Type[] { typeof(Test), typeof(String) });

    // Define parameters
    var parameterBuilder = myGetMethod.DefineParameter(
        position: 1, // 0 is the return value, 1 is the 1st param, 2 is 2nd, etc.
        attributes: ParameterAttributes.None,
        strParamName: "test"
    );
    var attributeBuilder
        = new CustomAttributeBuilder(typeof(FromServicesAttribute).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes), Type.EmptyTypes);
    parameterBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(attributeBuilder);

    // Define parameters
    myGetMethod.DefineParameter(
        position: 2, // 0 is the return value, 1 is the 1st param, 2 is 2nd, etc.
        attributes: ParameterAttributes.None,
        strParamName: "stringParam"
    );

    // Generate IL for method.
    ILGenerator myMethodIL = myGetMethod.GetILGenerator();
    Func<string, string> method = (v) => "Poop";

    Func<Test, string, string> method1 = (v, s) => v.Name + s;

    myMethodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Jmp, method1.Method);
    myMethodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    return tb.CreateType();
}
```